# Getting center of specific screen in virtual desktop qt

Tags: c++, qt

Hey guys i need to get resolution of specific screen in virtual desktop under qt and move window around given screen. I tried

```
QRect screenSize = desktopWidget.availableGeometry(desktopWidget.screen(ui.monitorNumberComboBox->currentIndex()));
```

and now when i execute

```
void MyWindow::setCoordinates(int x, int y)
{
    this->move((x-(this->width())/2),(y-(this->height()/2)));
    //sets center of window on given coordinates
}
window->setCoordinates(screenSize.width()/2, screenSize.height()/2);
```

it works great but only for primary screen. Is there a possibility to use it for different screen, selected by index?

Answer (score -1):

I think you need to call:

```
[..]
QPoint center = screenSize.center(); // Get the center of the screen rect.
window->setCoordinates(center.x(), center.y());
```

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work for screens other than the main one, anyway thanks for your time